# Flutter stop ListView from rerendering it's children

Tags: dart, flutter

The list items my ListView is populated with each contain initState methods fetching data from the internet. So when I scroll through the list and the items get out of view, they get out of the widget tree and when I scroll up to them again they will rerender, fetching the data again.

I don't want this to happen, so is there any way to either cache the data or to not delete them out of the rendertree when i scroll?

Comment: Can you post your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please review this question and answer. [how to build dynamic list from http server in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51378641/how-to-build-dynamic-list-from-http-server-in-flutter/51388537#51388537)

What you should do is cache the data once it is received the first time. You will also need to use `ListView.builder`. This widget has an `itemBuilder` method.  You should define your own method called `getItem(int index)`. This method will use the index to lookup your data in the cache, and if it's not found, then it will make the http request and save it in the cache.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
 return ListView.separated(
  physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
  padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
  shrinkWrap: true,
  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
  itemCount: (transaction.length > 10 ? 5 : transaction.length),
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
     return Container(
       child: (transaction.length == 4 ? Text('No Latest Transaction', textAlign: TextAlign.center,style:
       TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 18.0, color: Colors.black),) :
       ListTile(
         dense: true,
         trailing: Text(
           transaction[index].network,
           style: TextStyle(
               inherit: true, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700, fontSize: 16.0),
         ),
         leading: Padding(
           padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 4.0),
           child: Material(
             elevation: 10,
             shape: CircleBorder(),
             shadowColor: Color(0xFF63013C), //ChangeColor(transaction[index].network).withOpacity(0.4),
             child: Container(
               height: 50,
               width: 50,
               decoration: BoxDecoration(
                 color: ChangeColor(transaction[index].network),
                 shape: BoxShape.circle,
               ),
               child: ClipRRect(
                 borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                 child: Icon(
                   NetworkIcon(transaction[index].network),
                   color: Colors.white,
                 ),
               ),
             ),
           ),
         ),
         title: Row(
           mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
           children: <Widget>[
             Text(
               'N' + transaction[index].amount,
               style: TextStyle(
                   inherit: true,
                   fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                   fontSize: 16.0),
             ),
           ],
         ),
         subtitle: Padding(
           padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
           child: Row(
             mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
             children: <Widget>[
               Text(transaction[index].phoneno,
                   style: TextStyle(
                       inherit: true,
                       fontSize: 12.0,
                       color: Colors.black45)),
               SizedBox(
                 width: 20,
               ),
               Text(transaction[index].category,
                   style: TextStyle(
                       inherit: true,
                       fontSize: 12.0,
                       color: Colors.black45)),
               Spacer(),
             ],
           ),
         ),
       )),
     );
  },
  separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
    return Divider();
  },
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue. I was able to fix it by using the `SingleChildScrollView` widget. You can render your child widgets inside a Column to make it scrollable. So something like,

```
SingleChildScrollView(
  child: Column(
     children: [WidgetA, WidgetB, WidgetC]
  )
)
```

This may not be the most efficient way to render but works if you have a smaller list or a list with a fixed size. Hope this helps.